# Shadowbox not opening on hover until clicked once

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, shadowbox

I am using Shadowbox to display image on hover, but for some reason it works only AFTER I clicked the link for the first time. I am using Chrome and FireFox, neither working right.

You can see here: http://www.impero.co.za/demo/hsrc/site_content/view/how-we-curate-data

There is an anchor called "Qualitative Data". It does not open the Shadowbox on hover, but once I have clicked on it once, it opens, and from there onwards, it opens on hover.

As far as I can see from shadowbox's website, and Stackoverflow resources posts, I am doing this right.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance,

Kobus

Comment: [Don't just post a link to your example.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) try to find the problem in your code, remove anything unrelated, and post a short sample of the code. (Unrelated: the text in the menu items on that site is too hard to read. Naarow font.)

Comment: I would suggest you actually work on making sure that it NEVER opens on hover instead. You shouldn't violate a users' expectations; no one is going to expect hovering over a random link in the body of the text will open a page-covering pop-up. Even worse, since you are not [underlining your links](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040510.html) and have fairly poor contrast between the color of your text and the color of the links, it is easy to unwittingly mouse-over the link and be confused as to why this thing just popped up.

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, thank you - I didn't know about this one page. I know now :-)

Comment: @UselessCode: Thanks for the info. This is the client's design, not mine. I just implement the PHP around it. I would prefer not to use that font and style either. As for the hover - that is what the client wants. I suggested that I don't think it is a good idea, but they still want it. *shrug*

Comment: @KobusMyburgh Unless your client is dead-set on having it appear with a shadow box you might want to use [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) instead, its pop-up is a little less disruptive and can point its callout back to the link that spawned it to make it more obvious why it appeared.

Comment: @UselessCode: Thank you - that is a very good suggestion. I will try and rather use that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Shadowbox.open(this);` in your `onmouseover` attribute, e.g.

```
<a id="shadowbox[gallery]"
   href="http://www.impero.co.za/demo/hsrc/assets/uploads/images/qualitativedata.jpg"
   onmouseover="Shadowbox.open(this);"
   rel="shadowbox[gallery]">Qualitative Data</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, Matthias, this works 100% as I would want it to work.